# Software for robotic-like job

Tags: automation, macros, autohotkey, clipboard

What's the software that can help on my boring repetitive job?
My daily job involve lots of data entry, copy paste, using internal system to search/input/add and look for data. AFAIK there's some useful clipboard software that can keep long history and switch between them. Anyone can recommend some useful one?

Other than that, is there any chance that I can "macro" the whole process? For example, open this website, then select the option and submit the form, then input and search, if XXX exist then copy XXX to clipboard. I did before some macro thru AutoHotKey for web game like using Page Down then detect color region, if only the color within specific range then only trigger mouse click on some coordinate. Is there any other software or programming language that can easily do that? The platform to be macrod are some internal programs and some web based applications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either [Short Key/Short Key Lite](http://www.shortkeys.com/) or [Macro Express](http://www.macros.com/) would do what you need.

Comment: I ain't figured how yer fixin' these but gracias.

Comment: [Comparison of his and your revisions](http://superuser.com/posts/367546/revisions) (click on all options on the left to see the visual and actual differences)

Comment: Sorry.  I appreciate your attempt but I need more specifics than that.  All I can see from the comparison is that his works and mine doesn't.  It tells me nothing about how or why.  Sorr... I iz Be Dense.

Comment: @OGChuckLow haimg added properly formatted links to your post. Notice the difference with the `Show the markdown source diffs side-by-side` display.

Comment: will try out the short key, thanks.
regarding the macro is there anything or other programming language that can be so powerful like autohotkey?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html).

> CLCL is a clipboard caching utility.
>
> - All clipboard formats are supported.
> - Template can be registered.
> - Pop-up menu is displayed by "Alt+C."
> - Menu can be customized.
> - Item is paste automatically.
> - Picture is displayed on a menu.
> - Tool tip is displayed on a menu.
> - The format to leave and the format to save can be set up.
> - The ignored window can be set up.
> - The paste key for every window can be set up.
> - Function is extensible with plug-in.
> - freeware

[image]